Pine Script: How to an alert message in a strategy with "max_intraday_loss"?
how can i create an alarm in my strategy when i use the daily loss function? I ll use the {{strategy.order.alert_message}}  as a placeholder. Would appreciate your help. Thanks
loss = input.float(title="loss (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=0.8)
strategy.risk.max_intraday_loss(loss, type=strategy.percent_of_equity,  alert_message= message_long)

when i try the above, i get this error "Cannot call 'strategy.risk.max_intraday_loss' with argument 'alert_message'='message_long'. An argument of 'series string' type was used but a 'simple string' is expected"
